# Is there a way to round up a fraction in PHP even if it's less than half (.499... or lower)?

Tags: php

In some PHP script, I have a number 5.0000001 that must be rounded to 6.0. Is there a way to round **any** fractional number greater than 5.0 up to 6.0? (Even if the fraction is less than .5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **`ceil`** mathematics function in ***many*** languages does the opposite of truncation which takes any number that's not a whole number and rounds it up to the proceeding whole number no matter the size of the decimal.

You can also find out more from the php website : https://www.php.net/ceil

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for PHPs [`ciel`](http://php.net/ceil) command.